# Is it possible to display menu bar in Popup using ShowModalDialog

Tags: javascript, popup, showmodaldialog

I have one question, please.

Now I'm using ShowModalDialog method to display Popup.

It doesn't display Menu Bar (File,Edit,...) in Popup. I need to show Menu Bar in Popup because I want to click 'Print' under File menu.

I can't find a way to see the Menu Bar in Popup using ShowModalDialog. 
Is it possible to display the menu bar and how should I write in JavaScript coding like menubar: yes?

I wrote the code as the following.

```
<script>
    /*
    * ShowModalDialog
    */
    function popupWindow(x_URL, x_ARG, x_WIDTH, x_HEIGHT){
        var x_OPT = "dialogHeight: "+x_HEIGHT+"px; "
        +"dialogWidth: "+x_WIDTH+"px; "
        +"edge: Raised; center: Yes; resizable: Yes; status: Yes;";
        window.showModalDialog(x_URL, x_ARG, x_OPT);
    }
</script>
<s:url id="printURL" action="myaction" method="print"></s:url>
<s:submit name="btn_print"
value="Print"
onclick="popupWindow('%{printURL}','',1200,600);return false;" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to make the web browser show a menu bar when using `window.showModalDialog` (see references at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.showModalDialog) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536759%28VS.85%29.aspx)). However, you can create your own print button inside the modal window like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.print();">Print</button>
```

The key there is the call to [`window.print()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.print).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I have one more question pls.
I wrote that sentence <button type="button" onclick="window.print();">Print</button>. During the printing process, this button is displayed on print page. I don't want to display this button on print page. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Fortunately, I found the answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741425/how-can-i-hide-button-before-printing-and-show-it-when-printind-process-has-been) for my question mentioned in comment. Thanks!